# Popup view controller in Split view controller similar to iMessage?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I have application with `Split View controller.`
I want to have popup view controller that shows, when there are some special circumstances (e.g user is not registered.).
You can see this in Apple Messages application in iPad.
Is there a way to do this without third party controllers?

**EDIT:** I found solution: In storyboard user can set Form Sheet in simulated mectrics section of atributes inspector.After that with modal transition can open popup view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If you are using Storyboard.... if using nib replace storyboard with your nib file

 // Create and configure a new detail view controller appropriate for the selection.
            UIViewController *objViewController = [UINavigationController new];

            objViewController = [self.storyboard                                   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomePopupNavigationController"];                

            objViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
            objViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

            [self presentViewController:objViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

            //it's good to do this after presentModalViewController, but not neccessary if you using form sheet size of your view controller
            objViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 540, 620);
            objViewController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
```

//vKj

Comment: `objViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;` This line is key from a Treasure.Thanks!